# Replacing Multiple Strings with Images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, replace

I currently have `54` image icons and at later stages I will have over `200` image icons that will need to `replace` various `strings` throughout an entire `html` page. In all cases these `strings` will be `encased in {}`.
Example

```
{A}, 
{B}, 
{C},
{ABC},
{DEF}, 
{1},
{2},
{34},
etc.
```

So far this is all I've come up with that works but only applies individually.

```
<script>
   var link = '<img src="path_to_IMG" height="15px" width="15px">';
$("body").children().each(function () {
$(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/{B}/g, link) );
});         
</script>
```

I would like the script to cycle through all cases dynamically changing the path_to_IMG and replacing the string with the image link. Please excuse me, I'm very much so a novice in Javascript so my example below shows elements as if were partially PHP.  This script would be ever-evolving as new icons and the paths to those icons will continuously need to be added over time.

```
<script>
   $path    = 'website.com/images/';
   $img_loc = 'IMG_GENERIC.png';
   $link    = '<img src=".$path.$img_loc." alt="symbol" height="15px" width="15px" />';

   $("body").children().each(function () 
    {
      case('{A}'):
            $img_loc = 'IMG_A.png';
            $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/{A}/g, link) );
      case('{B}'):
             $img_loc = 'IMG_B.png';
            $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/{B}/g, link) );
    });         
</script>
```

Comment: what does this have to do with PHP? there's no PHP in the code you've posted

Comment: I’d store all of this into an object - use the string you need to replace as the key, and what you need to replace it with as the value. Then just loop over the object, and … replace.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an array of objects describing search and replace strings and loop over it to do a search and replace. Here's a minimal example.

```
let searchAndReplace = [
  { search: "{A}", replace: "path-to-image-a.png"},
  { search: "{B}", replace: "path-to-image-b.png"}
];

for(let s of searchAndReplace) {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(s.search, s.replace);
}
```

Of course you could populate that array dynamically with PHP.

You may also want to use regular expressions for the search term.

```
var searchAndReplace = [
  { search: /{A}/g, replace: "path-to-image-a.png"},
  { search: /{B}/g, replace: "path-to-image-b.png"}
];
```